# ANDROID Alarm Manager repetition until a date

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am creating an app similar to an alarm clock and would like to know how to do some things.

I can get sound notification on a certain date at a certain time, I would like to know how you can edit it (deleting the old one) and how to make it sound every 5 minutes up to a certain time that I decide

I create a notification at 7:00 1/1/2001 
and I say that in the settings should sound every 5 minutes until 02.01.2001

How do I make it happen?

class broadcast receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context
            .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);

    Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
    PendingIntent oi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setContentIntent(oi).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.avvio)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notific_title))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notific_subject));

    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/"
            + R.raw.audio);
    mBuilder.setSound(sound);
    mgr.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

    }`
```

class notificationreceiver is only a layout..

class allarm

```
public void createAlarm(String data,String ogni){

    StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(data," ");
    String date = s.nextToken();
    String time = s.nextToken();

    StringTokenizer a = new StringTokenizer(date,"/");
    StringTokenizer v = new StringTokenizer(time,":");

    String giorno = a.nextToken();
    String mese = a.nextToken();
    String anno = a.nextToken();
    String ora = v.nextToken();
    String minuti = v.nextToken();


    Calendar myAlarmDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    myAlarmDate.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    myAlarmDate.set(Integer.valueOf(anno), Integer.valueOf(mese)-1, Integer.valueOf(giorno), Integer.valueOf(ora), Integer.valueOf(minuti), 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


Intent _myIntent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent _myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, _myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myAlarmDate.getTimeInMillis(),_myPendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the reset in the `BroadcastReceiver` of your app:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive( Context context, Intent src ) {
    Date now = new Date();
    Date until = getUntilDateFromPreferencesForExample();
    if( now.after( until ) ){
      PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( app, 0, src, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
      ((AlarmManager)context.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE )).cancel( pi );
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: so you have to add my code into your `onReceive()` method to cancel the alarm